# Sum and drag a formula with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

Basically what I want to do is create that formula on VBA and then apply it to all cells on row 12+ (Simulating the effect of dragging my formula all across that row)

That way I get

- On B2 ->   =B8-SUM(B3:B7)
- On C2 ->   =C8-SUM(C3:C7)

and like that for everything on that row.

Comment: `Range("B2:F2").Formula = "=B8-SUM(B3:B7)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the formula to the entire range in one step. Excel will update the relative references across the columns.

```
Range("B2:F2").Formula = "=B8-SUM(B3:B7)"
```